# How do I return something only after a for-loop finishes executing in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, completionhandler

I want to get the number of 'pieces' logged each day within a period and add it up, so I am using a for-loop and iterating through the period. However, it seems to be performing the following asynchronously, so 0 just gets returned. Here is my code:

```
func getPiecesInPeriod(period: Int, uid: String) -> Int{
    //period = #days
    var pieces = 0
    for i in 0..<period {
        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-86400*i))
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Log").document(getDayMonthYear(date: date)!).getDocument() {(document, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else if document?.get("total pieces") != nil {
                pieces += document!.get("total pieces") as! Int
            }
        }
    }
return pieces
}
```

I tried using a completion handler:

```
func getPiecesInPeriod(period: Int, uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    //period = #days
    var pieces = 0
    for i in 0..<period {
        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-86400*i))
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Log").document(getDayMonthYear(date: date)!).getDocument() {(document, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else if document?.get("total pieces") != nil {
                pieces += document!.get("total pieces") as! Int
                print(document?.documentID)
                print(pieces)
            }
            completion(pieces)
        }
    }
}
```

but no matter where I put the line 'completion(pieces)' it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the completion handler to do this, and then you need to make sure you only call it once you have the data for all periods. With that definition in mind, it's actually not that hard: if you keep a counter of how many pieces you've already loaded, you can check that against the total you need to load.

So something like:

```
func getPiecesInPeriod(period: Int, uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    //period = #days
    var pieces = 0
    var count = 0
    for i in 0..<period {
        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-86400*i))
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Log").document(getDayMonthYear(date: date)!).getDocument() {(document, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else if document?.get("total pieces") != nil {
                pieces += document!.get("total pieces") as! Int
                print(document?.documentID)
                print(pieces)
            }
            if count++ = period {
                completion(pieces)
            }
        }
    }
}
```