# Swift 4 completion handler: Array remains empty

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, completionhandler

I'm trying to fill an array when fetching users from Firebase. When I set a breakpoint, I can see, that all users are appended to the array, but when the debugger is done, the array is empty again.

```
func firebaseRequest(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[User], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        var tempFirebaseUsers = [User]()
        
        self.firebaseFunctions.fetchUsers { (userFB, error) in
            
            if let user = userFB {
                print("User: ", user)
                tempFirebaseUsers.append(user)
            } else if let error = error{
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
        }

        completionHandler(.success(tempFirebaseUsers))
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your completion handler too early. When your `completionHandler(.success(tempFirebaseUsers))` runs, the `tempFirebaseUsers.append(user)` hasn't run yet.

To fix this, move the call to the completion handler into the callback:

```
func firebaseRequest(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[User], Error>) -> Void) {
    
    var tempFirebaseUsers = [User]()
    
    self.firebaseFunctions.fetchUsers { (userFB, error) in
        
        if let user = userFB {
            print("User: ", user)
            tempFirebaseUsers.append(user)
            completionHandler(.success(tempFirebaseUsers))
        } else if let error = error{
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Okay, the array passed in the completionHandler contains values now. The problem is, that the completionHandler is called for each user, since this fetchUsers function returns one user at a time. How can I say: Wait to send the completionHandler, until every user is fetched and appended to the tempFirebaseUsers array?

Comment: There's only one call in the snippet you shared. But if you do this multiple times, I typically keep a counter, increment that inside the loop, and only call the completion handler once I've read the required number of documents. Here's one example of doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666162/how-do-i-return-something-only-after-a-for-loop-finishes-executing-in-swift/62666200#62666200

Comment: I've managed to fix it. I rewrote my firebaseFunctions.fetchUsers. THANKS A LOT for helping me with my completion handler!